How do I make the cards appear from left to right and go to the next line
I'm trying to create an online store. I need 5 products in a row. I tried to do it by function, but I see the cards underneath each other. How can I make a series of cards with 5 elements? When I use flex, the card doesn't look the same as it does now. I don't understand what the problem is. I have tried many ways, flex does not help, please help me.


 .product-card-container {
      display: flex;
      gap: 0.5rem;
      padding: 0.5rem;
      border: 1px solid green;
      justify-content: space-evenly;
    }
    
    .product-card {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: center;
      width: 200px;
      padding: 0 0.4rem;
      row-gap: 0.5rem;
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
    
    .product-card > img {
      object-fit: cover;
      width: 100%;
      height: 200px;
    }
    
    .product-info {
      flex-grow: 1
    }
    
    .nft{
      user-select:none;
      max-width: 300px;
      margin: 2rem;
      border: 1px solid #ffffff22;
      background-color: #282c34;
      background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(40,44,52,1) 0%, rgba(17,0,32,.5) 100%);
      box-shadow: 0 7px 20px 5px #00000088;
      border-radius: .7rem;
      backdrop-filter: blur(7px);
      -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(7px);
      overflow: hidden;
      transition: .5s all;
      .wrapper li{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 10px 5px;
    }
      hr{
        width: 100%;
        border: none;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #88888855;
        margin-top: 0;
      }
      ins{
        text-decoration: none;
      }
      .main{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        width: 90%;
        padding: 1rem;
        color: #c572e6;
        .tokenImage{
          border-radius: .5rem;
          max-width: 100%;
          height: 250px;
          object-fit: cover;
        }
        .description{
            min-height: 100px;
      max-height: 100px;
          margin: .5rem 0;
          color: #a89ec9;
        }
        .tokenInfo{
          display: flex;
          justify-content: space-between;
          align-items: center;
          .price{
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            color: #ee83e5;
            font-weight: 700;
            ins{
              margin-left: -.3rem;
              margin-right: .5rem;
            }
          }
          .duration{
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            color: #a89ec9;
            margin-right: .2rem;
            ins{
              margin: .5rem;
              margin-bottom: .4rem;
            }
          }
        }
        .creator{
          display: flex;
          align-items: center;
          margin-top: .2rem;
          margin-bottom: -.3rem;
          ins{
            color: #a89ec9;
            text-decoration: none;
          }
          .wrapper{
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            border: 1px solid #ffffff22;
            padding: .3rem;
            margin: 0;
            margin-right: .5rem;
            border-radius: 100%;
            box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 4px #000000aa;
            img{
              border-radius: 100%;
              border: 1px solid #ffffff22;
              width: 2rem;
              height: 2rem;
              object-fit: cover;
              margin: 0;
            }
          }
        }
      }
      ::before{
        position: fixed;
        content: "";
        box-shadow: 0 0 100px 40px #ffffff08;
        top: -10%;
        left: -100%;
        transform: rotate(-45deg);
        height: 60rem;
        transition: .7s all;
      }
      &:hover{
        border: 1px solid #ffffff44;
        box-shadow: 0 7px 50px 10px #000000aa;
        transform: scale(1.015);
        filter: brightness(1.3);
        ::before{
          filter: brightness(.5);
          top: -100%;
          left: 200%;
        }
      }
    }
    
    .bg{
      position: fixed;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      h1{
        font-size: 20rem;
        filter: opacity(0.5);
      }
    }
<div class="nft" onclick="addProd('11', products)" class="card" >
        <div class='main'>
          <img class='tokenImage' src="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/XXX.jpg') }}" alt="NFT" />
          <h2>Корзинка</h2>
          <p class='description'>XXX.</p>
        </div>
     </div>
 <div class="nft" onclick="addProd('11', products)" class="card" >
        <div class='main'>
          <img class='tokenImage' src="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/XXX.jpg') }}" alt="NFT" />
          <h2>Корзинка</h2>
          <p class='description'>XXX.</p>
        </div>
     </div>




Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a Stack Snippet using the <> icon.  See How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

I used flex for the display property on the .product-card-container class, and I changed the max-width:300px of the .nft to simple width: 300px, to appear as in your snippet, and a media query to adapt on smaller screens the width of the .nft's. The 5 products in a row will only be visible on larger screens, due to the width of them, so you can tweak around with the width for your needs.


.product-card-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.nft {
  user-select: none;
  width: 300px;
  /*was max-width*/
  margin: 2rem;
  border: 1px solid #ffffff22;
  background-color: #282c34;
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(40, 44, 52, 1) 0%, rgba(17, 0, 32, .5) 100%);
  box-shadow: 0 7px 20px 5px #00000088;
  border-radius: .7rem;
  backdrop-filter: blur(7px);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(7px);
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: .5s all;
  .wrapper li {
    margin: 10px 5px;
  }
  hr {
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #88888855;
    margin-top: 0;
  }
  ins {
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  .main {
    width: 90%;
    padding: 1rem;
    color: #c572e6;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    .tokenImage {
      border-radius: .5rem;
      max-width: 100%;
      height: 250px;
      object-fit: cover;
    }
    .description {
      min-height: 100px;
      max-height: 100px;
      margin: .5rem 0;
      color: #a89ec9;
    }
    .creator {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      margin-top: .2rem;
      margin-bottom: -.3rem;
      ins {
        color: #a89ec9;
        text-decoration: none;
      }
      .wrapper {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        border: 1px solid #ffffff22;
        padding: .3rem;
        margin: 0;
        margin-right: .5rem;
        border-radius: 100%;
        box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 4px #000000aa;
        img {
          border-radius: 100%;
          border: 1px solid #ffffff22;
          width: 2rem;
          height: 2rem;
          object-fit: cover;
          margin: 0;
        }
      }
    }
  }
   ::before {
    position: fixed;
    content: "";
    box-shadow: 0 0 100px 40px #ffffff08;
    top: -10%;
    left: -100%;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    height: 60rem;
    transition: .7s all;
  }
  &:hover {
    border: 1px solid #ffffff44;
    box-shadow: 0 7px 50px 10px #000000aa;
    transform: scale(1.015);
    filter: brightness(1.3);
     ::before {
      filter: brightness(.5);
      top: -100%;
      left: 200%;
    }
  }
}

.bg {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  h1 {
    font-size: 20rem;
    filter: opacity(0.5);
  }
}

@media (max-width: 320px) {
  .nft {
    max-width: 300px;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
<div class="product-card-container">
  <div class="nft" onclick="addProd('11', products)" class="card">
    <div class='main'>
      <img class='tokenImage' src="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/XXX.jpg') }}" alt="NFT" />
      <h2>Корзинка</h2>
      <p class='description'>XXX.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="nft" onclick="addProd('11', products)" class="card">
    <div class='main'>
      <img class='tokenImage' src="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/XXX.jpg') }}" alt="NFT" />
      <h2>Корзинка</h2>
      <p class='description'>XXX.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="nft" onclick="addProd('11', products)" class="card">
    <div class='main'>
      <img class='tokenImage' src="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/XXX.jpg') }}" alt="NFT" />
      <h2>Корзинка</h2>
      <p class='description'>XXX.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="nft" onclick="addProd('11', products)" class="card">
    <div class='main'>
      <img class='tokenImage' src="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/XXX.jpg') }}" alt="NFT" />
      <h2>Корзинка</h2>
      <p class='description'>XXX.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="nft" onclick="addProd('11', products)" class="card">
    <div class='main'>
      <img class='tokenImage' src="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/XXX.jpg') }}" alt="NFT" />
      <h2>Корзинка</h2>
      <p class='description'>XXX.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




All of the cards needs to be first level children of a flex container. You can learn more here for instance.


.product-card-container {
  display: flex;
  gap: 0.5rem;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  border: 1px solid green;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.product-card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 0 0.4rem;
  row-gap: 0.5rem;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.product-card>img {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}

.product-info {
  flex-grow: 1
}

.nft {
  user-select: none;
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: 2rem;
  border: 1px solid #ffffff22;
  background-color: #282c34;
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(40, 44, 52, 1) 0%, rgba(17, 0, 32, .5) 100%);
  box-shadow: 0 7px 20px 5px #00000088;
  border-radius: .7rem;
  backdrop-filter: blur(7px);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(7px);
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: .5s all;
  .wrapper li {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 10px 5px;
  }
  hr {
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #88888855;
    margin-top: 0;
  }
  ins {
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  .main {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 90%;
    padding: 1rem;
    color: #c572e6;
    .tokenImage {
      border-radius: .5rem;
      max-width: 100%;
      height: 250px;
      object-fit: cover;
    }
    .description {
      min-height: 100px;
      max-height: 100px;
      margin: .5rem 0;
      color: #a89ec9;
    }
    .tokenInfo {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
      align-items: center;
      .price {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        color: #ee83e5;
        font-weight: 700;
        ins {
          margin-left: -.3rem;
          margin-right: .5rem;
        }
      }
      .duration {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        color: #a89ec9;
        margin-right: .2rem;
        ins {
          margin: .5rem;
          margin-bottom: .4rem;
        }
      }
    }
    .creator {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      margin-top: .2rem;
      margin-bottom: -.3rem;
      ins {
        color: #a89ec9;
        text-decoration: none;
      }
      .wrapper {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        border: 1px solid #ffffff22;
        padding: .3rem;
        margin: 0;
        margin-right: .5rem;
        border-radius: 100%;
        box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 4px #000000aa;
        img {
          border-radius: 100%;
          border: 1px solid #ffffff22;
          width: 2rem;
          height: 2rem;
          object-fit: cover;
          margin: 0;
        }
      }
    }
  }
   ::before {
    position: fixed;
    content: "";
    box-shadow: 0 0 100px 40px #ffffff08;
    top: -10%;
    left: -100%;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    height: 60rem;
    transition: .7s all;
  }
  &:hover {
    border: 1px solid #ffffff44;
    box-shadow: 0 7px 50px 10px #000000aa;
    transform: scale(1.015);
    filter: brightness(1.3);
     ::before {
      filter: brightness(.5);
      top: -100%;
      left: 200%;
    }
  }
}

.bg {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  h1 {
    font-size: 20rem;
    filter: opacity(0.5);
  }
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
}
<div class="flex">
  <div class="nft" onclick="addProd('11', products)" class="card">
    <div class='main'>
      <img class='tokenImage' src="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/XXX.jpg') }}" alt="NFT" />
      <h2>Корзинка</h2>
      <p class='description'>XXX.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="nft" onclick="addProd('11', products)" class="card">
    <div class='main'>
      <img class='tokenImage' src="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/XXX.jpg') }}" alt="NFT" />
      <h2>Корзинка</h2>
      <p class='description'>XXX.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="nft" onclick="addProd('11', products)" class="card">
    <div class='main'>
      <img class='tokenImage' src="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/XXX.jpg') }}" alt="NFT" />
      <h2>Корзинка</h2>
      <p class='description'>XXX.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="nft" onclick="addProd('11', products)" class="card">
    <div class='main'>
      <img class='tokenImage' src="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/XXX.jpg') }}" alt="NFT" />
      <h2>Корзинка</h2>
      <p class='description'>XXX.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="nft" onclick="addProd('11', products)" class="card">
    <div class='main'>
      <img class='tokenImage' src="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/XXX.jpg') }}" alt="NFT" />
      <h2>Корзинка</h2>
      <p class='description'>XXX.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>



